# UWP ToString("C") taking language setting instead of custom currency setting

Tags: c#, localization, uwp

I am building a Windows 10 Universal app and I need to show an amount in the currency format specified by the user (Settings/Region/Additional Settings/Currency/Symbol).

For me that is specified to € and my language is set to en-GB.

amount.ToString("C") always returns the pound instead of the € symbol.  Probably because the CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture is set to en-GB.

I tried it in WinForms and WPF, and there the € shows fine.  How can I get it to work for Universal Apps?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the CultureInfo inside ToString to another country that uses euro:

```
amount.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("de-DE"))
```

Comment: yes, but the culture depends on the settings of the user as specified in Windows.  So I can't just set a standard culture.  I need to know how to get the currency setting from Windows.

Comment: Strange ...  for me it works fine if I change the Currency symbol from $ to € from Additional Settings. Are you sure that you have applied the symbol to the Positive currency format?